# PivotTable with dynamic Query to External Datasource

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

My question is less specifically looking for ideas to a solution, and more for a sanity check of my own solution since it's been a while (at least two major revisions) since I've worked with ADODBs in Excel VBA.

So the situation is this. I'm creating an Excel report for a user who wants to access large chunks of a database view that is much too big to fit in memory. The user needs to be able to access ALL of the view, so hardcoded filters are out of the question. Unless I'm missing a more elegant solution, what they need is to be able to dynamically control the filters on the connection in the form of a generated SQL statement, which feeds into the pivotcache and then tells the pivottable to refresh.

I created a "refresh" button which brings up a Form that has all the filters the user commonly needs. The user enters the filter values, I parse and validate them, form a proper SQL statement from the values. Then I run into a problem when I do this:

```
'this has to be dynamic becuase I'm distributing to multiple users, using different testing/production databases on different workstations.
mypivottable.PivotCache.Connection = "ODBC;" & driver & myserver & myuser & trusted & app & workstationid & databse

'this also has to be dynamic becuase of the sql filters
mypivottable.PivotCache.CommandText = sql
```

So I push the button and it works! after setting these properties the pivottable automatically refreshes because it knows there's new data behind the cache, and fetches the query results under the new criteria.

The problem is that when I look in the external datasource listing, every time I change these properties it creates a new connection and doesn't clean up after itself. After 100 uses, there are 100 connections laying around, 99 of them unused. If I delete ALL the connections, then it irreversibly breaks the pivottable.

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a programmatic way to clean up only unused connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to reset the connection if all you need to do is update the SQL statement. I actually had a similar issue to this and this is how I resolved it:

```
Sub test()
' add logic...

    ' then change sql code
    With ThisWorkbook.Connections("your connection name").OLEDBConnection
            .CommandText = Array("select * from mytable where id = 1") ' adjust accordingly
            .Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

All you really need to do is grab the current connection then update the CommandText property. By the way, I'm not sure why I needed to use `Array()` but I had issues without it.

I actually wrote a blog post about using SQL to create a pivot table ([link here](http://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/excel-create-pivot-table-using-sql/)). Maybe I should make another one about creating dynamic content :)